# Get mongod rs.status() results from a python script

Tags: python, mongodb

For monitoring purposees I try to get the output of the following shell commands but from a python script

```
:mongo --port 27040
-> enters mongodb shell
:rs.status()
```

see image
[image: mongo command]

The result of the command is json that I want to access outside the mongo shell to write it to a file, I can run other command in python using pymongo like:

```
import json, os  
# load mongo library
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir, 'pymongo-3.7.1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl'))

from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import OperationFailure, ConnectionFailure

#connection settings
port = 27040
hostname = "localhost"
#default database used by mongodb
database = "test"

try:
    # connect to the database
    client = MongoClient(hostname,int(port))
    db = client[database] # select the database
    serverstats = db.command("serverStatus")
    serialized_serverstats = json.dumps(serverstats, default=json_util.default)
    print serialized_serverstats
except Exception as e:
    print("Unhandled Error is %s" % e)
```

This runs something equal to running db.serverStatus() in the mongo shell.
But how do I run rs.status() form inside a python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
db = client ['admin']
db_stats = db.command({'replSetGetStatus'  :1})
```

If you want to check what's the underlying command of any shell command:

```
> rs.status
function () {
    return db._adminCommand("replSetGetStatus");
}
>
```

Comment: If you can't get what you want from `replSetGetStatus`, check the implementation of printSlaveReplicationInfo (`> db.printSlaveReplicationInfo`), you can actually see it's code, which is what you want.